# html table with fixed header , horizontal scroll and dynamic column width

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying for the last complete week to have html table with fixed header, dynamic column widths and horizontal scroll. There are many options already available but each one lacks or misses a part of requirement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to find everything you need for that with either http://foundation.zurb.com or http://getbootstrap.com.

Answer (score 0):

@ashish - Not too sure on the dynamic width aspect, but I could possibly point you in the right direction with your other concerns. As far as the header, try something like this:

```
.th { position: fixed; }
```

For the horizontal scroll, try adding a container div around the table in your HTML, like so:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">

  <table>
  ... table content ...
  </table>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!